# node fs.mkdir gives errno -2 in ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express

I have the following code working fine in my local environment:

```
if (!fs.existsSync(dirName)){
            fs.mkdir(dirName, function(err){
                if(err){ 
                 console.log(err);
                 callback(err);    // echo the result back
               }else{
                   callback(null, result);
               }
            });
        }else{
            callback(null, result);
        }
```

But when I run the same code, I get the following error:

```
{"err":{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"mkdir","path":"public/img/profile/7f603130-6aee-11e6-9199-9308857da48d"
}}
```

This can potentially be a permission problem for creating directories in my linux server but I don't know how to solve it. Any thoughts?

Comment: ENOENT stands for Error NO ENTry, which usually means there is no such directory. Update path to `./public/img/profile/7f603130-6aee-11e6-9199-9308857da48d` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.mkdir()` will only create *one* directory.

In your case, it will try and create a directory called `7f603130-6aee-11e6-9199-9308857da48d` in the (assumed to already existing) directory `public/img/profile/` (relative to the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)).

If that last full path doesn't already exist, you'll get an `ENOENT` error.

You can use a module like [`mkdirp`](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp) to create all intermediate directories as well.